# Transaction Log Backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I check with SQL query whether transaction log backup every 15 minutes JOB is created or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try looking in msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps and msdb.dbo.sysjobs for one with either the correct name or the correct command.

```
SELECT j.name, js.step_name, js.command
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js ON j.job_id = js.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules jsch ON j.job_id = jsch.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules sch ON jsch.schedule_id = sch.schedule_id
WHERE sch.freq_subday_type = 4
AND sch.freq_subday_interval = 15
```

The documentation for freq_subday_type and freq_subday_interval can be found on the [Microsoft Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187320.aspx).

```
freq_subday_type of 4 = minutes
freq_subday_interval = how many minutes
```

Comment: Thank you...but how to check whether backup is taking every 15 minutes or not

Comment: The query above will list all jobs which are scheduled for every fifteen minutes.